# Spring Data MongoRepository - Shared repository vs Service to Service call

Tags: mongodb, web-services, spring-boot, mongorepository

I have a Spring Boot driven micro service architecture with a requirement to save audit logs from different services into a database table.

Database is MongoDB and application uses the MongoRepository interface.

Now since its a micro services architecture with around 20 services running parallely, I am not sure if the reprository interface that I have for the audit log collection shall be part of every Micro Service or only one service and then service to service calls to store the data through a single route (API driven) or any third approach.

Basically the trade off, I believe is between the performance in terms of the number of open connections with MongoDB on one hand and latency of the service to service calls architecture.

I am not even sure if having repository interface redundantly on all the service will have any impact on the number of open connections.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Thanks.